# Android callbacks and code re-usage

Tags: android, kotlin

In a fragment, I have a downloading code. and I'm sure I need the download function in the other fragments too.

So I want to make it separate file as a library from the fragment, but the code contains some android callback methods which stacked on the Activity and I don't know how to handle it if I move it to another file (Class).

The download code in the fragment,

```
private fun beforeDownload() {
    // check permission
    val externalPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    if (externalPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), REQUEST_ID_STORAGE_PERMISSION)
    } else {
        onDownload()
    }
}

/** Android call-back method after requesting permission **/
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    beforeDownload()
}


private fun onDownload() {
    if (media >= 100000000) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "The media is over 100Mb", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        downloadMediaJob = launch(UI) { downloadMedia() }
    }
}

// Android receiver when download completed
private val onDownloadComplete = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.download_complete_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

suspend private fun downloadMedia() {
    downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    ...
    downloadedFileId = downloadManager.enqueue(request)
}
```

and the callback methods are

**onRequestPermissionsResult**

**onDownloadComplete**

How can I move them to MediaDownload class so that making it reusable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Fragment **needs** to implement it's own lifecycle callback, but that call back can simply delegate to a method on an instance of an object.

For example in your code above:

```
private fun beforeDownload() {
    // check permission
    val externalPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    if (externalPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), REQUEST_ID_STORAGE_PERMISSION)
    } else {
        onDownload()
    }
}

/** Android call-back method after requesting permission **/
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    beforeDownload()
}
```

You should just move the beforeDownload() method to some "model" class, create or inject an instance and then call the `beforeDownload()` method on that instance.

```
class SomeModel() {
   fun beforeDownload() {
      ...
   }
}
```

Each Fragment still needs the lifecycle method, but the main part of the code can be shared in the SomeModel class

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: 
    Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    instanceOfSomeModel.beforeDownload()
}
```

The only way to complete remove the redundancy of having to implement even the minimal lifecycle method,  would be to subclass the Fragment and add the call you your method in the override in the subclass, but you don't want to do that!